# DMZ (Portforwarding) in OpenVPN

Tags: vpn, port-forwarding, openvpn, nat, dmz

I am running an self-hosted openvpn server with few clients. I want to expose 1 client to the external network, how can I do that? I see similar option in paid admin panel, but I'm using the free version which offers only a command line interface (CLI). If the complete exposure of a client is not possible, then I want to forward the ports without manually changing iptables each and every time.

Current structure is something like that:

```
+------------+
|            |
|  Client 1  +--------------------+
|            |                    |                +----------------------+
+------------+                    v                |                      |
                               Internet <---------->   Self-Hosted        |
+------------+                    ^                |   OpenVPN Server     |
|            |                    |                |   Community Edition  |
|  Client 2  +--------------------+                |                      |
|            |                                     +----------------------+
+------------+
```

Now I want to expose the client 2 to the public network (internet) through the VPN server. I can do that manually exposing ports using IP tables. But if a new port need a new rule in IP table, which I have to put manually. I am not very proficient with IP tables or openvpn administration, also exposing port manually is not effective enough (though may good for security perspective).

I want to expose the client 2 through the vpn server for once and all. How can I achieve that goal?

Comment: "Paid admin panel" Does this mean you are using a free product hosted by someone else? Have you checked if this feature is included in the service you're not paying for?

Comment: i am using core openvpn by hosting myself. it's cli only

Comment: Then what is the "paid admin panel" you're referring to?

Comment: @music2myear openvpn offer a web-ui, that is the paid one.

Comment: So, you're trying to see if you can do port forwarding in the free version of a self-hosted OpenVPN setup. Please EDIT your question to make that clear. Also, you'll want to include relevant information about what you have tried and the research you have done on this issue.